# Плавное развертывание блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Есть некий блок с информацией о пользователе(имя, био, и т.п.), который так же включает в себя две кнопки, удаление пользователя и редактирование информации. При нажатии на кнопку редактирования внутри этого блока появляется форма, по которой можно редактировать данные. Вопрос заключается в том, как сделать плавное увеличение высоты блока, в котором появлятся форма. Пробовал сделать анимацию, применяя ее к самой форме, используя @keyframes,но анимация работает только на саму форму. Внешняя часть самого блока открывается все также резко.

[image: ![]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Все стили:
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(47, 46, 46);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.header {
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 25px 100px; /* 25px - сверху и снизу, 100px - слева и справа*/
    font-weight: 600;
}

main{
    margin: 50px 100px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

aside{
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    float: left;
}

main .user {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #3e8fa0;
    padding: 20px;
}

main .delete-icon,
main .edit-icon{
    float: right;
    font-size: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #222;
}

main .edit-icon:hover,
main .delete-icon:hover{
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

form input:not([type='checkbox']), /* Все input кроме того, у которого type checkbox */
form textarea, 
form button{
    width: 90%;
    padding: 15px 5%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 0;
    background: #222;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

form input:not([type='checkbox']):hover,
form textarea:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: 0.3s;
}

form input[type='checkbox']{
    margin: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form button {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

form button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.user form{
    margin-top: 20px;
    animation: edit-form 3s forwards;
    max-height: 413px;
    transition: max-height 3s;
}

.user form input:hover,
.user form textarea:hover,
.user form button:hover{
    transform: scale(1.01);
    background: #363636;
}

@keyframes edit-form{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```
class User extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            editForm: false
        }
    }
    user = this.props.user
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='user'>
                <IoCloseCircleSharp onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.user.id)} className="delete-icon"></IoCloseCircleSharp>
                <IoCreateOutline onClick={() => {
                    this.setState({
                        editForm: !this.state.editForm //Установка противоположного значения для editForm
                    })
                }} className="edit-icon"></IoCreateOutline>
                <h3>{this.user.firstname} {this.user.lastname}</h3>
                <p>{this.user.bio}</p>
                <b>{this.user.isHappy ? 'Happy :)' : "Not happy :("}</b>
                
                {this.state.editForm && <AddUser user={this.user} onAdd={this.props.onEdit}></AddUser>} 
            </div> // на 27 строке говорится то, что если значение editForm == true, в таком случае выводится форма и при нажатии на Add происходит редактрирование
        )
    }
}

export default User
```

```
class AddUser extends React.Component {
    userAdd = {}
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            firstname: "",
            lastname: "",
            bio: "",
            age: 1,
            isHappy: false
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form ref={(el) => this.myForm = el}> 
                <input placeholder='First Name' onChange={(e) => this.setState({ firstname: e.target.value })}></input>
                <input placeholder='Last Name' onChange={(e) => this.setState({ lastname: e.target.value })}></input>
                <textarea placeholder='Biography' onChange={(e) => this.setState({ bio: e.target.value })}></textarea>
                <input placeholder='Age' onChange={(e) => this.setState({ age: e.target.value })}></input>
                <label htmlFor='isHappy'>Are you happy?</label>
                <input type='checkbox' id='isHappy' onChange={(e) => this.setState({ isHappy: e.target.checked })}></input>
                <button type='button' onClick={() => {
                    this.myForm.reset() // Очищает введенные значения в форме
                    this.userAdd = {
                        firstname: this.state.firstname,
                        lastname: this.state.lastname,
                        bio: this.state.bio,
                        age: this.state.age,
                        isHappy: this.state.isHappy
                    }
                    if(this.props.user){
                        this.userAdd.id = this.props.user.id
                    }
                    this.props.onAdd(this.userAdd)}
                }>Add</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default AddUser
```

Comment: Покажите кад блоков, кнопки отображения, а так же стилей, которые применяются к блокам

Comment: @SwaD Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Скорее всего тебе необходимо увеличивать значение  от  `transform:scale(0)`  до `transform:scale(1)`  того как блок пояиться. Поскольку у тебя, насколько я понял, в DOM дереве до нажатия того блока и нету.... то после нажатия, и его появления, блок должен рождаться с  `transform:scale(0)` а потом уже или на CSS class тидай ту анимацию, или через JS постипенно увиличивай размеры. Можешь попробовать ещё через `height`